# Create a `hasmany` which has a `hasmany` with loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

Hi is it possible to create a chained `hasmany` relationship like this:

Customer has Sensors
and
Sensors has Meterings

`Customer` -> `Sensors` -> `Metering`

So that i can access Meterings over the Customer Model.

For Example: `http://localhost:3000/api/Customers/1/Sensors/2/Meterings`

Is this possible in anyway with loopback?

Comment: You can chain model relations with include filter. 
http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Include+filter

Answer (score 1):

You can create [`hasAndBelongsToMany`](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasAndBelongsToMany+relations) and [`hasManyThrough`](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasManyThrough+relations) relations to achieve this. It's likely that your API call would end up looking something like:

`/Customers/1?filter={"include":["meterings"],"where":{"sensorId":2}}`